# Pyglet not working on MacBook

Tags: macos, crash, python

I have installed Pyglet on my mac for python 3.8 but it isn't working .

By that I mean when I  type `pyglet.font.add_file('DIN Next W01 Light.ttf')` to add that font into my file it shows an error

No idea what the error is about

It runs perfectly in Windows but on the Mac it shows error:

````
2020-08-13 03:35:27.643 Python[15910:1241698] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a069bca0
2020-08-13 03:35:27.646 Python[15910:1241698] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a069bca0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff362dbb57 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6ef895bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3635abe7 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff362403bb ___forwarding___ + 1427
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3623fd98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000109e461f2 TkpInit + 408
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000109db5aac Initialize + 2454
    7   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000109c17dc4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000109c17a98 _tkinter_create + 1144
    9   Python                              0x00000001098ef4ee _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 430
    10  Python                              0x00000001098eea5a _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 42
    11  Python                              0x00000001099ad5a4 call_function + 724
    12  Python                              0x00000001099aa576 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25190
    13  Python                              0x00000001099ae0d6 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
    14  Python                              0x00000001098ee5fb _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 523
    15  Python                              0x00000001098ef8cf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    16  Python                              0x000000010993dd51 slot_tp_init + 145
    17  Python                              0x00000001099396a9 type_call + 297
    18  Python                              0x00000001098ee871 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 433
    19  Python                              0x00000001099ad474 call_function + 420
    20  Python                              0x00000001099aa617 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25351
    21  Python                              0x00000001099ae0d6 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
    22  Python                              0x00000001099a4234 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    23  Python                              0x00000001099e18f1 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
    24  Python                              0x00000001099e116a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 890
    25  Python                              0x0000000109a009db pymain_main + 6875
    26  Python                              0x0000000109a00f2a _Py_UnixMain + 58
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff70131cc9 start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```/Users/mananvyas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python "/Users/mananvyas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/QUIZ PROJECT/FINAL PROJECT.py"
2020-08-13 03:35:27.518 Python[15910:1241698] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to (null)
2020-08-13 03:35:27.643 Python[15910:1241698] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a069bca0
2020-08-13 03:35:27.646 Python[15910:1241698] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a069bca0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff362dbb57 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6ef895bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3635abe7 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff362403bb ___forwarding___ + 1427
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3623fd98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000109e461f2 TkpInit + 408
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000109db5aac Initialize + 2454
    7   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000109c17dc4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000109c17a98 _tkinter_create + 1144
    9   Python                              0x00000001098ef4ee _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 430
    10  Python                              0x00000001098eea5a _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 42
    11  Python                              0x00000001099ad5a4 call_function + 724
    12  Python                              0x00000001099aa576 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25190
    13  Python                              0x00000001099ae0d6 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
    14  Python                              0x00000001098ee5fb _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 523
    15  Python                              0x00000001098ef8cf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    16  Python                              0x000000010993dd51 slot_tp_init + 145
    17  Python                              0x00000001099396a9 type_call + 297
    18  Python                              0x00000001098ee871 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 433
    19  Python                              0x00000001099ad474 call_function + 420
    20  Python                              0x00000001099aa617 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25351
    21  Python                              0x00000001099ae0d6 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
    22  Python                              0x00000001099a4234 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    23  Python                              0x00000001099e18f1 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
    24  Python                              0x00000001099e116a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 890
    25  Python                              0x0000000109a009db pymain_main + 6875
    26  Python                              0x0000000109a00f2a _Py_UnixMain + 58
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff70131cc9 start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
````

And if i try to run it in IDLE it just shows this

[image]

There is no syntax error as it runs perfectly in Windows

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we see the code?

Comment: Either it's not the correct object for the method, or there's something about the fontname it doesn't like. Are you sure there's an underscore in the method name? That's not very pythony.

Comment: @TonyWilliams  I just installed the font in my mac and removed that ```pyglet.font.add_file('DIN Next W01 Light.ttf')``` line and it worked no idea what was the issue bt it works

Comment: @benwiggy yes there's an underscore. as I said it works perfectly in windows only in mac it has issues

Comment: @MananVyas Yes, but font handling is very different. As the python code is 'high-level', it will have a different effect on the 'engine' below.